# Restore js file with chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I accidentally deleted a HTML file with dreamweaver. I really would like to get this file back, my backup was not ok. So I would like to retrieve the file using the cache of my browser Chrome. I Googled and found this: [LINK](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html) But it doesnt work for me, when I download the file and look at it in Notepad all I see is strange characters.

What else can I try to get my file back with Chrome cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you download on this site is a gzip file, if you open that in notepad you will get much the same as on the chrome://cache site. You need to extract it with [7zip](http://www.7zip.org) or a similar tool first.

Comment: Sorry its actually a html file, I will change this in question

Comment: I will change my answer then

Comment: Are you sure? 7zip tells me "cant open fileblablaba as archive" even though I just want to unzip it, which has nothing to do with archiving. Maybe Im passing the wrong urls somehow..?

Comment: i made it like this (and it worked): 1. copy all text from a file in chrome cache 2. paste it on the website you linked 3. download the something.html.gz file 4. right-click -> 7zip -> extract file here

Comment: Didn't work, it just freezes. I tried a link of a js file and that one worked. So I think the problem is the difference in url. I can't make sense of the urls, so I don't know which one to open. Anyway I will look at it when Im home. Thanks for your answer, did not know they are zipped:)

Answer (score 2):

NirSoft's ChromeCacheView worked perfectly for me.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html

Note that the option to restore the actual files is not that obvious.  F4 does it.

Comment: Thank you for including the F4 instruction, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It would not be easily extractable from it's hexadecimal representation.

I have recently created a script for extracting files from Chrome and Firefox cache. Check it out at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/zxcmehran/b4cab69b70166187f5cb).

See the usage guide in [this post](https://medium.com/@zxcmehran/recover-the-past-4b721d73badd).

Comment: This saved my day after a huge js file upload failed with zero bytes, no FileZilla and NotepaddPP histories. Thank you.